# A way to ignore exit status in gitlab job pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab ci in order to create pipeline with a job using docker.
this job has a specific command which might fail. for example checking S3 file exists or not, if not , I will create it.
The problem is, when I run

```
aws --no-verify-ssl --endpoint-url https://${S3_END_POINT} s3 ls ${location}
```

When the file doesn't exists, the whole job fails, so I can't reach the code which checks if exit status is 0 or 1 in order to create the missing file.

Is there any way to still use the exit status and not letting the pipeline fails?

NOTE:
my job is written like regular script (not array of commands): using the "- |"

Comment: Append one space and `|| true`?

Comment: @Cyrus but i do want to know the real exit code

Comment: Append one space and `|| echo $?`?

Comment: I end up using the command inside "if" statement, it will catch the status code instead of letting gitlab-ci catch it.. thanks! ;)